# Act on Right Mouse Button click on Button

Tags: libgdx, input

I want to be able to listen for a right mouse click onto a `TextButton`. Is this possible without removing the default `ClickListener` of the `TextButton`? If yes, how? Or should I use a different listener?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually really simple. All you have to do is add another `ClickListener` which listens for Right Clicks (the default only listens to left clicks). To do this all you have to do is this:

```
someButton.addListener(new ClickListener(Buttons.RIGHT)
{
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y)
    {
        //do whatever
    }
});
```

*Note that this also works for middle clicks (`Buttons.MIDDLE`)*

Comment: Dude.  this is legit!

Answer (score 6):

There are three main ways (that I know of) to obtaining input in LibGDX.
The first is as you said, changing the  `ClickListener`, the second will be setting the setting the current screen as an implementation of  `InputProcessor` , and the third will be obtaining the mouse click through a new class, or a sub-class to get the input.
I'll elaborate on each:

1. The first way: Changing the ClickListener. Pretty straight forward, lets say you have a text button named  `onOffSwitch`, if you'd want to recieve input on it, you'd write the following code: 
   `onOffSwitch.addListener(new ClickListener(){ });`
    This will create a new `ClickListener` to use to recieve any input from the button.
    When you use this you can add method like `enter` to see whenever the mouse is hovering over the buttton, or when the player is touching the button.
2. The second way: Setting a new `InputProcessor`, this will basically create an inputprocessor which will be your entire screen. 
    I don't recommend using this since it requires more than one methhod and is often not needed, all that's needed is a little digging around on how to get the listeners you need.
    To implement this way, you need to make your class implement the `InputProcessor` and implement the needed methods.
3. The third and last way, which I assume is the one you'll use is the following:
   To use this way you'll create a new instance of `InputProcessor` and apply it to `Gdx.input`:

   ```
   class AwesomeGameClass {
   public void init() {
       Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {
           @Override
           public boolean TouchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
               if (button == Input.Buttons.LEFT) {
                   //check if the x and y coordinates are the same as your text button (using TextButton.getPrefWidth() & TextButton.getPrefHeight()) and if so then invoke the onMouseDown method.
                   return true;
               }
               return false
           }
       });
   }
   private void onMouseDown() {
   }
   ```

   }

The code I got from here, and you can see what else there is there that I might have missed. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644429/libgdx-mouse-just-clicked)
Except that you can read up on materials in the LibGDX github, which is located [HERE](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki)
Or look at the data concerning TextButtons in [HERE](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/TextButton.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it sent me on the right path, but the solution was even easier ;)